# When/how to benefit from parallel processing of scripts?

Tags: performance, bash, unix, parallel-processing

I have a sequence of scripts to run on a computer with 1 physical & logical core.

I have tried running them in sequence, and also forking them with something like the bash script below. The background processes, running in parallel, actually took longer than running them in sequence.

My question is: Under what circumstances should a workload like this be run in parallel? That is, must I have particular hardware or can I do this more efficiently with the single-processor computer that I have?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run them in sequence...

T1=$(date +%s)
python proc_test1.py
python proc_test2.py
python proc_test3.py
T2=$(date +%s)
T=$((T2-T1))

echo "Scripts took ${T} seconds."


# Now fork them...

T1=$(date +%s)
python proc_test1.py &
python proc_test2.py &
python proc_test3.py &
wait
T2=$(date +%s)
T=$((T2-T1))

echo "Scripts took ${T} seconds."

exit 0
```

Comment: Btw, with bash: `SECONDS=0; <do something>; echo $SECONDS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel processing usually becomes beneficial when hardware is available. For example, if you had three logical CPUs, then three computations could occur simultaneously. Thus, ideally, if you ran proc_test1.py three times with forks with three available processors, all three would finish in the same time it would take to run just one instance of proc_test1.py.

In other words, given sufficient hardware, running three proc_test1.py's in serial will take three times as long as running them with forks.

Now, given that you just have one hardware cpu, it makes sense that the parallel jobs would run more slowly than the serial ones, as each python program will be competing with each other for cpu time. The cpu stopping one job and resuming another costs cpu time itself.

For example, say you had 6 oranges and two hands, and you had to hold all 6 oranges for 5 seconds total. Say it takes you one second to pick up or swap out oranges. You could do this task in serial, and pick up two oranges at a time for five seconds before swapping for a new pair. This would take you

```
1 + 5 + 1 + 5 + 1 + 5 
= 3 * 5 + 3 = 18
```

seconds to complete.

Now suppose the parallel analogy. Then all 6 oranges are begging to be picked up and you holding one does not mean that you wont immediately drop it for an alternative. There isn't necessarily an upper bound on how long it will take you to complete the task as we have defined it, so suppose that you have to hold the oranges for at least 2.5 seconds before you swap them out, and you only swap in pairs. Then, it will take you

```
1 + 2.5 + 1 + 2.5 + 1 + 2.5 + 1 + 2.5 + 1 + 2.5 + 1 + 2.5 + 1 
= 3 * 5 + 7 = 22
```

seconds to complete. Note that by "forking", it takes you 22% longer to hold 6 oranges for 5 seconds each. Since you have two hands, it still takes you 15 seconds to complete the task, but there is a variable overhead in switching time based on your strategy. Note that if you had 6 hands, it would take only 7 seconds to complete the task.

Thus when you have more processors, fork processes, otherwise you're just juggling jobs on limited hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Your simple question is in practice extremely hard to answer in general. In real life I would always measure to see if reality agrees with my theory.

An example where reality did not agree with my theory was on my Intel Core i7. It has 4 cores and has hyperthreading. This would suggest that running 8 threads in parallel will be optimal: You will be using the 4 processing units and use 4 additional threads for keeping the pipelines filled.

However, Core i7 has 6MB of *shared* cache. It just so happened, that the working set of my data fit inside the 6MB. So I saw an extreme speedup by running 1 thread instead of 2 or even 8: Running more than 1 would simply flush the cache all the time. This would not have been true if the cache had not been shared, but it just shows that it is not simple to say when parallelizing will be faster.